# How can I set JFrames to be undecorated from a look and feel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, look-and-feel

I am making a look and feel and it is going well. While I was making the look and feel I thought that it would look much better if the title bar was dark theme like the rest of the look and feel. I want to keep the code cross platform though. Is there anyway I can make a jframe undecorated from my look and feel? I would then replace the title bar with custom buttons for closing, minimizing, and maxamizing the window based on the current OS.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: 1) Use [`setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(boolean)) with a variety of PLAFs and check the result. 2) (Also) See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Tip: Here is what you might see if running code described in the first point. [Multiple frames, with Metal showing a customized title bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3uTX.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I set JFrames to be undecorated from a look and feel?

That's not the job of a PLAF, so they don't offer that ability.

OTOH a PLAF ***can*** change the look of a title-bar, as seen here:

[image]

The PLAF's style of title bar only appears if the following method is called: [`JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(boolean)).

> Provides a hint as to whether or not newly created JFrames should have their Window decorations (such as borders, widgets to close the window, title...) *provided by the current look and feel*. If `defaultLookAndFeelDecorated` is true, the current `LookAndFeel` supports providing window decorations, and the current window manager supports undecorated windows, then newly created `JFrame`s will have their `Window` decorations provided by the current `LookAndFeel`. ..